# Bundle js vs bundle.js.gz

Tags: javascript, webpack, compression

I used webpack to generate my bundle.js but since I was using some thrid party libraries the size is about 1MB. I use the compressed plugin and got a bundle.js.gz of 200kb. I used it and change the header to let the browser know it is compressed and it worked perfect. I am just worried about any side effects I am not seeing at first.

Can anyone tell me what could go wrong.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Do you have any particular side effects you are worried about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't foresee any problems. Another option, depending on your host, is to configure gzip on your http server. This will gzip on the fly and cache it for future requests (dependent on config).

Here are instructions for configuring Apache & nginx:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/gzip-compression-on-apache-and-nginx